# Iccube: Pie chart value of misc (other)

Tags: google-visualization, reporting, iccube, iccube-reporting

I am using a pie chart and have following problem:
There are many items which have a value less than 5 %.
Is there an option that those items will sum up to an item "misc".

On a different report it sums up to "misc" if the value is less than 0,1 %
It is possible to set that value?

Iccube Version 5.1.7

Cheers 
J

[image]

Comment: is this a google viz or an icCube chart ?

Comment: It is a Google/Generic Chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine small slices using the following configuration option:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#slice-visibility-threshold

To configure this in the reporting application v5.x use the advanced section of the chart configuration(Chart Edit -> Widget Tab -> Advanced Properties ->  Extra Options)

```
:{
    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0.01,
    pieResidueSliceLabel: 'Misc' 
}
```

Example of the configuration:
[image: Example of the configuration]